# ONGR ElasticsearchBundle mapping virtual fields to ElasticSearch

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, doctrine-orm, ongr

I want to do a full name lookup in ElasticSearch when I have a first name and last name in MySQL.

I have looked at `cross_fields` and `copy-to`, but neither support the flexibility of being able to search part or all of the name in a `MatchPhrasePrefixQuery` as far as I can tell.

So what I want to do instead is add a field to ElasticSearch that is `$firstName . ' ' . $lastName`

I have mapped my user entity fields to ElasticSearch using the `@ES` decorator.

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @ES\Property(type="keyword")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"default"})
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("firstName")
 */
private $firstname;
```

But how do I add a virtual `fullName` column to ElasticSearch so that I can search that field instead of the 2 separate fields?

Is there a way to add it using the decorators so that it is automatically handled with the other fields and data migrations etc., without having to make a separate import script for it and doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick shot (not tested):

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ES\Property(type="keyword")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"default"})
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("fullName")
 */
private $fullname;

/**
 * Get fullname
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullname()
{
    return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. That did it perfectly. I thought I had already tried that, but apparently not.